# Invalid Cognito Phone Number

Tags: amazon-web-services, import, amazon-cognito

We have been trying to upload users to cognito via the import jobs. However, seems like the phone_number attribute refuses to accept Indian mobile numbers. The format for phone number is like `+919839999999`. The `phone_number_verified` field is set to TRUE. Below is the error I receive:
`[FAILED] Line Number 21 - The User Record contains an invalid phone number for the phone_number attribute.`

From the documentation, cognito does say that after first two characters of country code, it looks for area code but I am not sure if that'll be the case when using cellphone numbers.

Comment: Are you editing the console via the console, or the CLI/an SDK? You could attempt to test it using the CLI by modifying phone_number in the expected JSON format.

Comment: @lightyagami I am trying to upload users using the import job from the console. It only accepts csv files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems if you are using google sheets, you have to re-convert the format to text of the cellphone fields or manually edit the csv. It works then